Issue with LLM-specific metrics in Google Cloud Vertex AI Evaluation Framework
I'm encountering an error when trying to use LLM-specific metrics like "groundedness" or "coherence" with the Google Cloud Vertex AI evaluation framework for the Gemini model. Standard metrics like ROUGE and BLEU work fine, but I specifically need the LLM-related metrics. I'm following the example below:
"prompt_engineering_evaluation_rapid_evaluation_sdk.ipynb"
Source: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/generative-ai/blob/main/gemini/evaluation/prompt_engineering_evaluation_rapid_evaluation_sdk.ipynb
Environment

Google Cloud Vertex AI
vertexai SDK (not the older aiplatform)
Python version: 3.10.12
google-cloud-aiplatform version: 1.63.0

Code snippet
import vertexai
from vertexai.preview.generative_models import GenerativeModel
from vertexai.preview.language_models import TextEmbeddingModel
from google.cloud import aiplatform
# ...

PROJECT_ID = "pa*****413"  # @param {type:"string"}
LOCATION = "us-central1"  # @param {type:"string"}

vertexai.init(project=PROJECT_ID, location=LOCATION)

instruction = "Summarize the following article"

context = [
    "To make a classic spaghetti carbonara, start by bringing a large pot of salted water to a boil. While the water is heating up, cook pancetta or guanciale in a skillet with olive oil over medium heat until it's crispy and golden brown. Once the pancetta is done, remove it from the skillet and set it aside. In the same skillet, whisk together eggs, grated Parmesan cheese, and black pepper to make the sauce. When the pasta is cooked al dente, drain it and immediately toss it in the skillet with the egg mixture, adding a splash of the pasta cooking water to create a creamy sauce.",
]

reference = [
    "The process of making spaghetti carbonara involves boiling pasta, crisping pancetta or guanciale, whisking together eggs and Parmesan cheese, and tossing everything together to create a creamy sauce.",
]


eval_dataset = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "context": context,
        "instruction": [instruction] * len(context),
        "reference": reference,
        "prompt": [instruction] * len(context)
    }
)

prompt_templates = [
    "Instruction: {instruction}. Article: {context}. Summary:",
    "Article: {context}. Complete this task: {instruction}, in one sentence. Summary:",
    "Goal: {instruction} and give me a TLDR. Here's an article: {context}. Summary:",
]

metrics = [
    "rouge_1",
    "bleu",
    "coherence",
    "groundedness",
]

eval_task = EvalTask(
    dataset=eval_dataset,
    metrics=metrics,
    experiment="test-eval"
)

gemini_model = GenerativeModel("gemini-pro")

experiment_name = "eval-sdk-prompt-engineering"  # @param {type:"string"}

summarization_eval_task = EvalTask(
    dataset=eval_dataset,
    metrics=metrics,
    experiment=experiment_name,
)

run_id = generate_uuid()
eval_results = []


for i, prompt_template in tqdm(
    enumerate(prompt_templates), total=len(prompt_templates)
):
    eval_result = summarization_eval_task.evaluate(
        prompt_template=prompt_template,
        model=gemini_model,
    )

    eval_results.append(
        (f"Prompt #{i}", eval_result.summary_metrics, eval_result.metrics_table)
    )

Error message
Error: 400 Failed to make prediction request. If you're using a new project, expect a delay and retry in a few minutes. Error: /PredictionServiceV1.GenerateContent to [2002:a05:6681:452a::]:4339 : APP_ERROR(3) User has requested a restricted HarmBlockThreshold setting BLOCK_NONE. You can get access either (a) through an allowlist via your Google account team, or (b) by switching your account type to monthly invoiced billing via this instruction: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/invoiced-billing.

What I've tried

Changing metrics to standard NLP metrics like ROUGE and BLEU (works, but not what I need)

Explicitly setting and removing safety settings for the GenerativeModel
safety_settings = {
    HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_UNSPECIFIED: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE,
    HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE,
    HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE,
    HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE,
    HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE,
}

model = GenerativeModel("gemini-pro", safety_settings=safety_settings)


Updating dependencies and checking API quotas

Verifying project configuration and permissions (tried with both personal owner account and company account)

Using different LLM-specific metrics (e.g., changing from "groundedness" to "coherence")


Questions

Has anyone successfully used LLM-specific metrics like "groundedness" or "coherence" with the Vertex AI evaluation framework for the Gemini model?
Are there specific permissions, project settings, or API enablements required for these advanced metrics?
Is there a beta program or allowlist for using these LLM-specific metrics with the Gemini model?
Are there any known issues or limitations with these metrics in the current version of the Vertex AI SDK?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Hi @Pedro P. Camellon, Could you check this document, and let me know if this is helpful for you or not ?

Hi @DhirajSingh. Thank you for trying to help. To clarify, I'm actually using the following safety setting in my code: HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_UNSPECIFIED: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE. I'm not using BLOCK_NONE at all. The error message mentioning BLOCK_NONE seems to be related to some internal default value that I don't have direct control over. Regarding the suggestion I saw in the link provided about monthly invoiced billing, unfortunately, that's not an option for me at the moment due to organizational constraints.

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
